# Android WebView opening link

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am coding an Android app in Android Studio, I have an Activity with a WebView and would like to know if there is a way to detect a hyperlink a user clicks in the WebView

I want to be able to detect if the link is **link1.com** it will continue and open like normal but if its **link2.com** it cancels and opens another activity

Answer (score 2):

Use this to Check the url and perform your task

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if(url.equals(link2)){
            Intent i = new Intent (Youractivityname.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startactivity(i);
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm sorta new to this so I'm confused on where to put it I can't put it in Activity's java file because it can't extend WebViewClient because it extends AppCompatActivity... I tried putting it in a separate class but I don't know if I'm supposed to register it or something?

Comment: Create another class in your Activity's Java file and Extend there.

Answer (score 2):

do as answered by Faizal Abbas.Create a class extending WebViewClient,override the method  shouldOverrideUrlLoading(),then set the WebViewClient to your webview.

WebView webView=yourWevView;
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

Answer (score 0):

For what you need, you have to use a `WebViewClient` like this:

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if(url.contains("link2.com")){//if url contains link2.com open new activity
            startactivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class)); //replace CurrentActivity with the activity where you are writing this code and SecondActivty with the activity you want to open
        }

        else {
            //do nothing, webview will load that link
        }

        return true;
    }    

});
```